# Trying to get status code from access_by_lua_file

Tags: nginx, logging, lua, openresty

I'm trying to get status code from response application and send it to external api bit in access_by_lua_file ngx.status or ngx.var.status always return 0 or 000. I use log_by_lua_file and get status code as my response application but I can't send it to external api because the API function is disabled is there another way to get status code and send it to external api

this my example code

logging.lua

```
local request_time = ngx.now() - ngx.req.start_time()
local data = {
    request_method = ngx.var.request_method,
    user_agent = ngx.var.http_user_agent,
    request_time = request_time,
    status = ngx.var.status,
    url = "http://" .. ngx.var.host .. ngx.var.request_uri,
    ip = ngx.var.remote_addr,
    time = ngx.var.time_iso8601,
    path = ngx.var.request_uri
}

local httpc = require("resty.http").new()
local output = cjson.encode(data)
ngx.log(ngx.ERR, ngx.status, ngx.var.status)
ngx.ctx.status_code = ngx.var.status
ngx.ctx.request_method = ngx.var.request_method
ngx.ctx.user_agent = ngx.var.user_agent
ngx.ctx.request_time = ngx.var.request_time
ngx.ctx.url = "http://" .. ngx.var.host .. ngx.var.request_uri
ngx.ctx.ip = ngx.var.remote_addr

-- ngx.location.capture("http://127.0.0.1:3232/api/create-log", { method = ngx.HTTP_POST, body = output })
-- ngx.location.capture_multi({"http://127.0.0.1:3232/api/create-log", { method = "POST", body = output}})

ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "dasdsadas ", ngx.var.status, " ", ngx.status, " ", ngx.var.upstream_status)

local res, err = httpc:request_uri("http://127.0.0.1:3232/api/create-log", {
    method = "POST",
    body = output,                    
    headers = {
        ["Content-Type"] = "application/json",
    },
})


if not res then
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "request failed: ", err)
end
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes auto;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format json_output '{"time_local": "$time_local", '
        '"path": "$request_uri", '
        '"url": "http://$host$request_uri",'
        '"ip": "$remote_addr", '
        '"time": "$time_iso8601", '
        '"user_agent": "$http_user_agent", '
        '"user_id_got": "$uid_got", '
        '"user_id_set": "$uid_set", '
        '"remote_user": "$remote_user", '
        '"request": "$request", '
        '"status": "$status", '
        '"body_bytes_sent": "$body_bytes_sent", '
        '"request_time": "$request_time", '
        '"request_method": "$request_method",'
        '"http_referrer": "$http_referer" }';

    
    init_by_lua_block {
        cjson = require("cjson")
    }
    error_log logs/error.log error;

    server {
        listen 8080;
        access_log logs/access2.log json_output;

        location /hello {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Cache-Control, Accept, Origin, X-Session-ID, Host";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, DELETE, OPTIONS, TRACE, CONNECT";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";

            if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
                return 200;
            }

            if ($request_method = HEAD) {
                return 200;
            }

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            access_by_lua_file lua/logging.lua;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3131;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

access_by_lua runs before the request is initiated to your upstream. Hence, the status codes won't be set and would be defaulted to 0.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62202290/9090571

The response & its status code is available in content_by_lua, header_filter_by_lua, body_filter_by_lua, or log_by_lua but you won't be able to directly initiate a httpc request because the API function is disabled.

There is a known workaround that I have used earlier using
https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxtimerat

```
local function push_data(request_method, http_user_agent, status, full_uri, args, remote_addr, time_iso8601, request_uri,request_time)
    local data = {
        request_method = request_method,
        user_agent = http_user_agent,
        status = status,
        full_uri = full_uri,
        args = args,
        ip = remote_addr,
        time = time_iso8601,
        path = request_uri,
        request_time = request_time,
    }

    local cjson = require "cjson"
    local output = cjson.encode(data)

    local httpc = require("/usr/local/openresty/nginx/resty/http").new()
    local res, err = httpc:request_uri("http://127.0.0.1:3232/api/create-log", {
        method = "POST",
        body = output,
        headers = {
            ["Content-Type"] = "application/json",
        },
    })

    if not res then
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "request failed: ", err)
    end
end

local ok, err = ngx.timer.at(0, push_data,
        ngx.var.request_method,
        ngx.var.http_user_agent,
        ngx.var.status,
        "http://" .. ngx.var.host .. ngx.var.uri,
        ngx.var.args,
        ngx.var.remote_addr,
        ngx.var.time_iso8601,
        ngx.var.request_uri,
        ngx.now() - ngx.req.start_time()
        -- any other variables you need to set
)
if not ok then
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "failed to create timer: ", err)
    return
end
```

Or, you could also use https://github.com/cloudflare/lua-resty-logger-socket although it is probably not maintained and has a bunch of open issues.